# Click handlers not firing on appended items

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some results that have items that get toggled, hidden/shown, etc. That bit works just fine except for the items that are appended to the bottom of the results. The click handler does not fire on them but work just fine on the others. I assume it has to do with reading the nodes at the time of page load. How do I get the appended items to also work?

```
<div class="event">
                            <a href="/profile/00000000">
                            <img class="user-image" src="https://graph.facebook.com/00000000/picture?width=100&amp;height=100">
                            </a>
                            <div class="event-info">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="event-time-location">
                                    <span class="user-name">Levi Thornton</span>
                                    <span class="user-action-time">Posted 21 minutes ago</span>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="event-caption">1
</div>                                                                      </div>
                                <div class="event-like-comment">
                                    <input id="js-eventId" type="hidden" value="201" name="eventId">
                                                                        <a href="#" class="event-liked hidden">liked</a><a href="#" class="event-like">like</a>                                 <a href="#" class="js-event-comment">comment</a>
                                    <a href="/shindig/201" class="event-view">more</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>


                            <div class="comments" id="comments-201" style="display: block;">
                        <div class="newComments">
                                <input id="js-eventId" type="hidden" value="201" name="eventId">
                                <textarea class="addComment" value="Write a comment..." placeholder="Write a comment..." title="Write a comment..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                        <!-- comments -->


                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
```

The jQ:

```
...
     // add like
     $(".event-like").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
                var likeBtn = $(this);
                $.post('/shindig/ajax-like-event', { eventId: $(this).siblings('#js-eventId').val(), userLogged: $('#js-userLogged').val(), ajax: true}, function(data){
                    if(data['success']){
                        likeBtn.hide();
                        likeBtn.siblings(".event-liked").show();
                    } else {
                        if(data['noaccess']){
                            window.location.href = data['url'];
                        }
                    }
                },"json");
     });
    // soft delete like
     $(".event-liked").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
                var likeBtn = $(this);
                $.post('/shindig/ajax-unlike-event', { eventId: $(this).siblings('#js-eventId').val(), userLogged: $('#js-userLogged').val(), ajax: true}, function(data){
                    if(data['success']){
                        likeBtn.hide();
                        likeBtn.siblings(".event-like").show();
                    } else {
                        if(data['noaccess']){
                            window.location.href = data['url'];
                        }
                    }
                },"json");
     });
    // hit bottom scrolling, load more results
     $(window).scroll(function() { 
         if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
             console.log('bottom');

             $.post('/index/ajax-feed-items-by-time', { pager: $("#js-pager").val(), ajax: true}, function(data){
                 $( ".feedContent" ).append( data );
                 $pager = $("#js-pager").val()+10;
                 $("#js-pager").val($pager);
             });
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
$(".event-like").click(function(event) {
```

with

```
$(document).on("click", ".event-like", function(event) {
```

and similarly throughout your code. It's called *event delegation,* and the best place to start reading about it is the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful!

After reading the jQuery documentation I looked up some other examples for other items like binding keypress, etc. This was simple example, but helpful. So I'm dropping it here for the next guy.

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/